# How to stop openerp 7 from redirecting to message tab after installing or upgrading a module

Tags: openerp-7

I was wondering how to stop openerp- 7 from redirecting to message tab after I installed a module, im developing a module every time I want to test the module I have to go to settings > installed modules > search for the module and upgrade this is really annoying ;( I want upgrading page stay where it is as like of openerp 6.1

Thank you,

Answer (score -1):

In terminal type your addons path and put -d *database name* and -u *module name* and start you server.